# How to send email in Project Event Handler onPublishing every time publish job failed?

Tags: eventhandler, ms-project-server-2013

i have made event handler to cancel project being published when the project has no baseline. I have to notify the owner of project every time it happen. What code that I need to make it send email every time the publish job failed?

Thx for answering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin alerts from Project Server to send emails to the owner of the queue job for failed queue jobs(the user who published the project).

1. Configure the 'Alerts and Reminders' in the PWA Settings (SMTP Server, From Address,...)
2. Go to '[PWA]/_layouts/15/pwa/Notification/Self_Notification.aspx' and make sure the 'Queue Job Failure Alerts' option is checked (should be checked by default).